# android toolbar menu padding margin remove aligment

Tags: android

android toolbar menu padding margin remove aligment 
toolbar menu icon gap remove extra spaces  please help me 
There is some padding or margin to the left of my toolbar 
 I don't know where it comes from and I don't know how to remove it.

my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_220sdp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/dark"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:title=" ">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ArticleImg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorArticle"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorProgressBar"
                    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    style="@style/myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
                    android:id="@+id/amvMenu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_comment" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my menu

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@id/imageStar"

        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Share"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@id/pat"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_pat_trans"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Share"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@id/patCount"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="1"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@id/Share"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_share_toolbar_trans"
        android:orderInCategory="400"
        android:title="Share"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is the problem with mipmaps. place your image in mipmap folders like given in this link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

Comment: It's not that there's extra padding or margin there. All of the menu items are the same size. If you want to wrap the width on one, it'd be easiest to just create your own `Button`s in the `Toolbar` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your ToolBar with below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think default menu item has default padding but you can use below link to make your own menuitem and use it in your menu.

https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/5835584

Comment: getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.comment_menu, menu);
        MenuStar = menu.findItem(R.id.imageStar).setChecked(true);
        MenuPat = menu.findItem(R.id.pat).setChecked(true); how to use

Comment: Post your code if possible for the menu things wherever you are using.

Comment: this.menu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.comment_menu, menu);
        MenuStar = menu.findItem(R.id.imageStar).setChecked(true);
        MenuPat = menu.findItem(R.id.pat).setChecked(true);
        patCount.setTitle(Likes + "");
        if(isFavourite.equals("yes")){
            MenuStar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_action_fav_yellow_toolbar).setChecked(false);
        }